# how to search multi types data in elasticsearch just like db's compound query

Tags: search, elasticsearch

how to search multi types data in elasticsearch  just like db's compound query.
I am a green hand about elasticsearch  ,I want to kown how to query data which in diffrent types.

Comment: can you add some mappings, schema, sample documents to support your post

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting comma between your types or indexes. For example, check the below example to match all your docs your multiple type

```
GET books/fiction,adventure/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

And also, you can search on multiple indexes:

```
GET logstash-*/warning/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

With this query, you can search on all the indexes whose name is start with "logstash-" or like type, comma will work for indexes.

You can check [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-index-multi-type.html) to get more information.

Comment: Please give some data example for more effective exampling.

Comment: Because tha answer is not related search condition. that is releated with url of the query

Comment: you can give some example if you can

Comment: just like sql select t1.a,t2.b,t3,c

Comment: select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.c_id left join t3 on ......where t1.name='' and t2.age>3....

Comment: You dont need any join if you use nosql. You should add your joined datas to your documents.

Comment: Please give your table example and I will try to create you an example structure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood you correctly but in ES you can search acroos multiple indexes and types [see link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html)

```
GET /twitter/tweet,user/_search?q=user:kimchy
```

This will search on tweet and user types